# Send Ajax from http page to https page

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am trying to send an ajax request to my secure page(https url) from non-secure page(http url), and my ajax request is aborting. But I can see response in debug console panel in the network tab.

my code is:

```
$("#loginfrm").loginForm({
               url: '<?php echo 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/ajax/loginfromajax' ?>',
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.substring(0, 3) === "Yes")
                    {
                       alert(1)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(2)
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }

            }).submit();
```

and i am attaching both error and what i got in response[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: HTTP -> HTTPS should work fine.  Are you saying you see the expected server response data in the console? How is the request aborting?

Comment: @AlexK. i attached screenshot over here. Please check.

Comment: do a return false in the success function, I suppose as you are not returning so the request is not stopping.

Comment: @RohitAilani No but its not coming to success function. its calling error. and in error responce i got ajax is aborted.